# get sitename from link by preg_match

Tags: php

i am trying to get the site name from the link

for example

i have this links

```
http://stackoverflow.com
http://www.google.com
```

i want get this results

```
stackoverflow
google
```

i am trying preg_match, but i have problem with expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need preg:

```
$parsed = parse_url($url);
$host = $parsed['host'];
```

e: this will also have the .com but you can trim TLDs off easier than you can match the whole domain out.

Comment: hello Collin, thanks for help but i need the name with out TLDs, i need it just like that (google) not (google.com)

Comment: explode on '.' and trim off the end of the array; you'll have to watch out for TLDs like .co.uk though

Comment: $parsed=explode('.',$parsed,2);     $parsed=$parsed[0];

Comment: Won't work if it has something like "www.google.com":


`print_r(explode(".", "www.google.com", 2)); => Array ( [0] => www [1] => google.com )`

Answer (score 0):

This is not as trivial as you might think. Your example has only `.com` TLDs, so if you limit it to that, you could do it like:

```
$result = preg_replace('(^(.+\.)?([^.]+)\.com$)', '$2', parse_url($subject, PHP_URL_HOST));
```

Which would return

```
stackoverflow
```

for example. However if you want to cover common domain suffixes, this is less trivial. You will find a list of known suffixes at Mozilla, it is the [PSL - Public Suffix List](http://publicsuffix.org/list/). It has some special syntax and [a PHP library](http://www.dkim-reputation.org/regdom-libs/) exists for it.